# Swift Dateformatter() converts wrong date

Tags: ios, swift, date, dateformatter

I want to convert a string into a date and use a small function. If I run the code the results is different from the input:

```
 let startDateString = "20-02-2022-15-00"
        print(startDateString)
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "DD-MM-YYYY-HH:mm"
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
        let startDate = dateFormatter.date(from: startDateString)
        print(startDate!)
```

the startDateString is "20-02-2022-15-00"
the result of startDate is: 2021-12-27 14:00:00 +0000

The results has the wrong format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM vs DD-MM-YYYY-HH:mm
and the date is about two month in the past.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `yyyy` not `YYYY`

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy-HH:mm"
```